# C how to search and count some specific words in a sentence

Tags: c, cpu-word

I started learning C lunguage since June 1,and I'm sorry that my English is'nt good.

I'm writing the program to search and count some prepositions like "at, in and on" in a sentence from the keyboard.
I'm currently writing codes like this.However, I cannot put in strings in "char word". 
Maybe, i cannot use some functions correctly,but i don't know where the problerm is.
Could someone help me??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


char word[50][30];
char prep_at[] = "at";
char prep_by[] = "by";
char prep_for[] = "for";
char prep_in[] = "in";
char prep_on[] = "on";
char prep_of[] = "of";
char prep_to[] = "to";
char prep_with[] = "with";
int count[6] = {0};

void GetLine(char str[]);
void GetWord(char str[]);
void ToLower(char str[]);
int main(void)
{
        char str[512];//最初のテキスト
        int i = 0;
        GetLine(str);
        GetWord(str);
        ToLower(str);
        printf("%s",word[1][1]);
        while (word != '\0'){
          if (strcmp(word[i],prep_at) == 0)
          count[0]++;
          i++;
        }      
      printf("%d",count[0]);
}

void GetLine(char str[])
{
        printf("文字列を入力:");
        scanf("%s",str);

}

void GetWord(char str[]){

  int i = 0;
  char *token;

  token = strtok(str," ");

  while(token != NULL){
    strcpy(word[i],token);
     //printf("%s\n",word[i]);  //単語を取り出せたか確認用
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
    i++;
  }
}

void ToLower(char str[]) {
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0' ) { //文字列の入っているセンテンスがEOSじゃなければループ
         str[i] = tolower((unsigned char)str[i]);
        // printf("%s\n",word[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give the input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: `scanf("%s",str);` will only read up to the first space character. To read a whole line use `fgets`. Also, suggest learning basic debugging - use a debugger and/or add debug print statements to trace the program execution to help you find where the first point of failure is.

Comment: The line `printf("%s",word[1][1]);` does not make sense. The expression `word[1][1]` is a single character. You cannot print a single character as if it were a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

welcome here!

one of the easiest way would be (for me) to create an array of words from the string you're getting. for example:

```c
int push_tok(char **arr, const char *tok, unsigned int size);

void foo(char *str)
{
  char **arr;
  char *tok;

  tok = strtok(str, ' ');
  // this is NOT a C function, define it yourself
  push_tok(arr, tok, arr_size);
  while (tok != NULL) {
    tok = strtok(NULL, ' ');
  }
}
```

https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok